# DB2 join files from 2 libraries

Tags: sql, database, join, db2-400

I have two libraries with files I need.  I have added both libraries to my ODBC library list.  I have tried using qualified names `datalib/fgdetl` and just `fgdetl` to join to tables in a library `apluslib`.  I am not having any success with this.

I am receiving the following error:

```
'42S02', '[42S02] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - USEML in APLUSV8FAQ type *FILE not found. (-204) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I am using ODBC and DB2/SQL query to pull data.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: " I am not having any success" is not very useful as a problem statement. Please include the queries you attempted and the respective error messages they produced (if by not having success you mean you did encounter errors).

Comment: @mustaccio done

Comment: Please add the SQL you tried. Are you using system or SQL naming? Did you verify that table USEML in library APLUSV89FAQ? Is USEML supposed to be a table?

Comment: Try datalib.fgdetl

Comment: @smoore4  do you want to add that as an answer, that seems to have done the trick for me!

Comment: Glad to know if works for you.  DB2 has its quirks for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System i Access ODBC Driver for DB2 uses a "." syntax of LIBRARY.FILE so just change your references to DATALIB.FGDETL and that should work.